# Firebase Database Android: need help to query data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[This is post class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BLwX.png)

[This is view count of post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cv4x.png)

I need to show top 5 view of my post in 1 recycler view but dont know how to query this, can someone help me?

Comment: Hello Tang, you need to be clearer. If you are having difficulties, post your work to give some context and explain what you are trying to do in a manner that would be more concise. It is also nice to show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

FirebaseDatabase always return result in ascending order so you have store Negative values in `CountViewAll` node
for example `1608266009991: -1`, `1608348562379: -3` like this

Then you could get your desire result by this way

```
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CountViewAll")
            .orderByKey().limitToFirst(5);

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String id = snapshot.getKey();
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(id)
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            // your data here
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```